# Creating a Unique ID for each record on Form Submission

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, form-submit, unique-key

I am new to Google Apps Script and have just begun to understand its working. A team member wrote out a simple simple script for some work i was doing. The script, in essence, triggered when any of a permitted  set of users (could vary) submits inputs to a 'Form Responses 1' spreadsheet via a Google Form.

Basically, I have a form that users complete and then submit. Upon submission, the script checks for the active row, The code adds 1 to the number of the cell W2 (which is a 'do not edit' cell, and replaces W2 with the new number, then checks if the Unique ID field on the Active Row is null and then replaces it with a concatenated ID thats alphanumeric. ie, it prefixes a set alphabetical prefix and takes the numerical input from the cell W2 on the same form to create a new Unique ID.

The script was working perfectly until the team member left and I removed her access from the Google sheets with no change to the script at all. I've been scrambling trying to figure out what happened after that, because since access was removed, when I haven't made any changes to my code. I have searched many different places and cannot seem to find what is wrong.

If i post it on a new google sheet, it's working fine .. but not on this sheet which already has around 900 critical entries.

Any guidance is welcome. the Script is as below. HELP!

```
  //Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl());

  //Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl());

  

  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get the active row
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  // Get the next ID value.  NOTE: This cell should be set to the last record counter value
  var id = sheet.getRange("X2").getValue()+1;

  Logger.log("HKG0"+id);

  // Check if ID column is empty
  if (sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue() == "") {
    // Set new ID value
    sheet.getRange(2, 24).setValue(id);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue("HKG0"+id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why your `id` not obtain value from the last row, else you will always return duplicate id even with +1

Comment: The code assumes that the active cell is from the last row and replaces W2 with a +1 from that row index.. Atleast, it used to.. not the cleanest code, i am told.. but it was working :(

Answer (score 2):

If your code is running off of a form submit trigger then this should work for you.

```
function formsubit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var id = sheet.getRange("X2").getValue() + 1;
  if (sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue() == "") {
    sheet.getRange(2, 24).setValue(id);
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).setValue("HKG0" + id);
  }
}
```

The Logger.log will help you to learn more about the event object. You can learn more about event objects [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

If you're looking for a unique id for each submission try: `const id = new Date(e.values[0]).valueOf();` it's the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to create a Unique ID for Each Row while data is entered using an HTML Form (External Source). This code is tested and working 100% in Google Apps Script!

```
// Code.gs
function getUniqueID(workSheet = 'default') {
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(workSheet);
  var current = prop != null ? prop : 0;
  var value = parseInt(current) + 1;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(workSheet, value);
  Logger.log(value);
  return value;
} // end of getUniqueID

function resetUniqueID(workSheet = 'default') {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(workSheet, 0);
} // end of resetUniqueID

// Usage
const uniqueID = getUniqueID('Data');
// Here 'Data' is name of workSheet
```